# How to configure gnome-terminal to use xterm-256color by default?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, gnome

When I start gnome-terminal and do `echo $TERM`, I got `xterm` as output.

I want it to be `xterm-256color`

I've considered the solution to add `'export TERM=xterm256color'` in my `.bashrc`. But I don't like this solution, what if I decide to switch shell? I have to add an other export to my new shell startup script?

So is there a better way to have automatically a 256 colors terminal when launching gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Copying [my answer from the same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/578798/11015) @javabrett pointed out:

You were well advised not to change your startup scripts, specially `~/.bashrc`. Any "terminal detection" using current `$TERM` or `$COLORTERM` in `~/.profile` is merely a guess, and may, as you said, cause trouble when using other terminals (say, Putty or xterm). The terminal emulator is supposed to set `$TERM`, and this should *not*  be changed from within the shell.

Gnome terminal, AFAIK, does not offer a configuration to change its `TERM`, but it does allow you to change your startup command, and that's all you need. Here is the trick:

```
Profile Preferences => Title and Command => Run a custom command instead of my shell
```

Then use the following command:

```
env TERM=xterm-256color /bin/bash
```

Just replace `/bin/bash` with your preferred shell if it's different. And no, you can't use `"$SHELL"` in that line for shell auto-detection ;) You have to hard-code it

Answer (score 5):

Beginning with `gnome-terminal` version 3.16, it defaults to `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: I'm on gnome terminal version 3.30 but it seem that `TERM=xterm-256color` is not the default. Explicitly specifying it with `export TERM=xterm-256color` does solve my [question related to bracketed paste](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25311/how-to-activate-bracketed-paste-mode-in-gnome-terminal-for-vim?noredirect=1#comment44475_25311) for example.

Comment: `TERM=xterm-256color` _is_ its default. If that's not what you see, either your shell initialization files tamper with it, or your distribution patches gnome-terminal (vte) to a different default.

Comment: Sorry that's because I was in a tmux session the $TERM variable then becomes screen.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good answer explaining how `gnome-terminal` doesn't allow `TERM` to be defaulted via its settings over at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233280/gnome-terminal-reports-term-to-be-xterm).

It suggests that this is a compile-time option, so it appears that setting `TERM` in a shell profile or startup script is the best and only option.  You might create a wrapper script or alias if you prefer.